# Lotus Notes 8.5.1

Tags: lotus-notes

Please understand that I am NOT a "power user..." so, I hope you can help. I work in a document dB in Lotus Notes and prior to the new iteration (8.5.1) installed this week, the scale on the ruler I used for setting margins in the dB was in inches. Now it shows up as a metric scale and I'd like very much to convert it back to inches. I've tried everything I can think of and for the life of me, cannot figure out how to do this. Can you help?
(Fyi, I work for the USA division of a European company...could they have made it so metric is the only choice?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, that your admins blocked that setting via Policy, but it is unlikely. Go to `File -> Preferences -> Regional Settings`.

There you will find a section called `Measurment settings for *Language*` and there you can choose between centimeters and inches.

Comment: Oh - aren't you just splendid!!!! It worked, and I thank you so very much! (Now I DO feel like a power user!" :) Thanks again